# With Homebrew, how to check if a software/package is installed?

Tags: install, homebrew

I'm installing a set of softwares/packages/formulas via homebrew with command like

```
brew install <formula1>
...
brew cask install <formula2>
...
```

I wonder if it's a good idea to verify if the softwares `<formula1>`, ..., `<formula2>`, ... are already installed and only trigger the above commands for the ones NOT already installed. If so, how?

Comment: If it's not critical to get this info from Homebrew, and you don't care how it was installed, `which <programname>` is faster than `brew list <programname>`.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
brew list <formula1> || brew install <formula1>
```

This will error on list and continue with install if not installed otherwise it will just list package files. (one could modify this further as a function or alias in .bashrc to make it easier to type)

Comment: How can this be done in a Brewfile?

Comment: @JackMoody It sounds like what you want to do is add it as a dependency in the brew file using `depends_on`

Comment: can confirm. `brew list python@3.9 &>/dev/null || brew install python@3.9;` works.

Answer (score 32):

It should also be noted that you can type `brew info <formula>` which will tell you whether or not a formula is installed. You can parse the response for "Not installed" and then run the installer if it finds the string.

Comment: the disadvantage of `brew info <formula>` is that it loads very slowly, as it has to fetch the statistics of the formula from the Internet. If you use `brew list <formula> | grep "No such keg"` (or something similar), the result will be displayed much faster.

Comment: `brew info` always has a exit code 0. so it's useless. `brew list python@3.9 &>/dev/null || brew install python@3.9;` works because it returns 1 when there's nothing found.

Comment: @airtonix Just because it always has an exit code of 0 doesn't make it useless. As I mention in my post this method requires that you parse the response.

Comment: @JoshCorreia nah it's useless. you want to know it failed or not. this is why exit codes exist.

Answer (score 7):

Building on the earlier answers, but packed into a ready to use function without all the homebrew logging:

```
brew_install() {
    echo "\nInstalling $1"
    if brew list $1 &>/dev/null; then
        echo "${1} is already installed"
    else
        brew install $1 && echo "$1 is installed"
    fi
}

brew_install "ripgrep"
```

Answer (score 2):

In similar vein to Hans Fredric, here is a snippet I actually use myself. The funny looking `<(cmd)` is Bash command substitution.

```
alias strip-empty="egrep -v '^\s*$'"
NOT_INSTALLED=$(comm -23 <(sort < apps.local) <( brew list --versions | awk '{print $1}' ) | strip-empty)
while read FORMULA; do
    brew install "$FORMULA"
done <<< "$NOT_INSTALLED"
```

Here, `apps.local` is just a list of apps to install, one per line. The improvement over just looping over each app and trying something like `brew_install` basically comes down to *speed*. Invoking `brew list` is slow (like up to a second), so I just do the test once by listing out all installed apps. The difference is very noticeable if you have > 5 apps.

If you need something with the same speed, but that works equally well with apps installed using a cask, you need something more elaborate ([like this](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/commit/f45b9eb821d06dbc33533168f5bb069a45495ed7#diff-ab72aa445325c73677e41ec6ee17e102101f4a2c17694e564655f8626d091395R34-R49)).

Comment: The `alias` is probably not required. Also, if you don't need `$NOT_INSTALLED` later, you could just run `comm ... | awk ... | while ...`.

Comment: Is absolutelyl not needed, but makes for less magic when reading it in half a year. You know, Dr. Bob: ExtractMethod to avoid needless comment. No need to invoke the RegExp cortex of the brain. And the piped version makes for much harder debugging when you want to change something - I went there first :-)

Comment: Agreed. I probably would include the grepping in the awk part but that's for sure is a matter of personal taste :-)