# Brew cask: I would like to check if the package/formula is already installed through brew or other means

Tags: macos, install, homebrew

I am trying to install some softwares using brew cask and I would like to check if the package/formula is already installed through brew or other means

I have a script that installs a list of softwares using brew cask and I dont want it to install a software that is already present on the machine

To achive this I referred to this question: [With Homebrew, how to check if a software/package is installed?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284379/with-homebrew-how-to-check-if-a-software-package-is-installed)

This is pointed me in the right direction but I can only avoid installing software that is installed via brew cask.

If the software is installed by downloading the dmg and is already present in the /Applications/ folder then it does not recognize that and it continues to install the software.

Is there a way to figure out if the application is installed via brew or any other means before my script starts installing it

Comment: "If the software is installed by downloading the dmg and is already present in the /Applications/ folder then it does not recognize that and it continues to install the software."

Use `find` command to search the `/Applications` and `~/Applications` folder for the target formula. List out all the matches in the console and ask user if they want to continue install or not.

Comment: @anki But the formula name and the Application name are not the same. For e.g. google chrome formula is google-chrome while the application name is 'Google Chrome' In this scenario I will have to keep on editing the script if the app decides to change its name.

Comment: regex, case insensitive search etc can be helpful here. I don't know any central list of all installed apps. You just have to search..

Comment: @anki I guess. I was hoping there was some way I could have extracted the app name from formula by brew before installing but it seems i do not have any other option.

Comment: You could parse the output of `brew cask info --json=v1 google-chrome` or `brew cask info google-chrome` to find the name the cask will install to. It won't help in case of renamed applications though.

Comment: @nohillside If apps are renamed then I dont really care. The user will have to figure it out but this command would definitely make my life easier. Thanks

Comment: @nohillside That did the trick. Awesome, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you know the name of the application. Then just test for existence of the application

```
if [[ ! -d "/Applications/APP-TO-CHECK.app" ]]; then
    # install APP-TO-CHECK
fi
```

Comment: But the formula name and the Application name are not the same. For e.g. google chrome formula is google-chrome while the application name is 'Google Chrome' In this scenario I will have to keep on editing the script if the app decides to change its name.

Comment: I tried to run your script but it gives me the following error: syntax error in conditional expression -> if [[ ! -d /Applications/Google Chrome.app ]]; then

Comment: Adding quotes to it fixed the  issue

Comment: @NickDiv Names with spaces always need to be quoted in the shell. As for the renaming issue: I don‘t see a failsafe way to cover all possible scenarios, and honestly consider this to be rare. If necessary I would just test for all known names.

Comment: That's the POSIX standard for test. It's sufficient to write `[` and `]`. This works in any shell. There is no need for `[[` and `]]`. See BashFAQ/031:  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Answer (score 1):

This is a primitive solution but it might help.

1. Download this [app](http://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/index.php) (it allows you to search hidden files.)
2. Search for the name of your application/repo you want to download.
3. If it is not there, then it is safe to say you don't have it.